# Load data to Java ehcache on Startup

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I am trying to use ehcache in Java server-side application to cache some data. How can I load some initial data to ehcache when server starts-up. Application is web-base application with Spring and Database connectivity. Also can anyone let me know how to refresh these caches periodically.

Thanks

Comment: is it a web application or a standard desktop application ?

Comment: It is a web application.

Comment: Are you using a framework such as spring ? consider adding more details about your project, such as frameworks used, whether you are using maven or not, all might effect the shape of the answer...

Answer (score 0):

### You can simply create a cache on server start up Implementing ServletContextListener Interface as follows.

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.myContexctListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

---

com.example.myContexctListener.java

```
package com.example;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class myContexctListener implements ServletContextListener {

    CacheManager cm;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        cm = CacheManager.getInstance();
            //2. Create a cache called "cache1"
      cm.addCache("cache1");
        // 3. Get a cache called "cache1"
        Cache cache = cm.getCache("cache1");

        // 4. Put few elements in cache
        cache.put(new Element("whatever", "yourObject"));

    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // 8. shut down the cache manager
        cm.shutdown();

    }

}
```

Then you can  retrieve the cache that was created and use it in your code

```
CacheManager cm = CacheManager.getInstance();

//3. Get a cache called "cache1"
Cache cache = cm.getCache("cache1");
cache.get("whatever");
```